# Problem with create txt file from application through .bat (cmd) - not set text with space and comma

Tags: batch-file

At application I have process that execute .bat file on computer and send through variable (set) text for create txt file
bat like:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "op=%1"
echo !op!>>C:\test\test.txt
chcp 866 > NUL
```

send text like:

```
^<office^>"(Town) - Street, number"^</office^>
```

Send procedure at cycle and first text write nice, but second in txt file looks like

```
<office>
```

and file is end.
Why it's happend?

Comment: what happens when you do `SET "op=%*"`? I cannot see any issues here, are you sure your application sends the same full string each time? Can you change it? I would rather wrap the entire string in double quotes as `"^<office^>(Town) - Street, number^</office^>"` and then expand on it to eliminate quotes in the batch.`SET "op=%01"`

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard try SET "op=%*" and all works nice, strange. Thank you!

Comment: So that tells me that you have a space somewhere in your string.. Try my suggestion please.

Comment: corection on my first comment, I made a typo with `SET "op=%01"` it should be `SET "op=%~1"`

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard yep, i'm understand that you want SET "op=%~1" - all works nice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time this can happen, is if there is a possible space in your string, perhaps the application is sending the string including a space? I would change the string for this reason to be wrapped in double quotes:

```
"^<office^>(Town) - Street, number^</office^>"
```

Then we can expand it to get rid of the quotes using `%~1`

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "op=%~1"
echo !op!>>C:\test\test.txt
chcp 866 > NUL
```

You can then test it and it should use the entire string each time:

```
batchfile.bat "^<office^>(Town) - Street, number^</office^>"
```

and the result remains the same in **test.txt** after 4 runs:

```
<office>(Town) - Street, number</office>
<office>(Town) - Street, number</office>
<office>(Town) - Street, number</office>
<office>(Town) - Street, number</office>
```